# How can I print the views title in node.tpl.php?

Tags: views, theming

I could print the view with this code in node.tpl.php.

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
print $view->execute_display('view_display_name', $args);
?>
```

How can I print the views title ?

Comment: There's a slightly shorter version of this code: [`print views_embed_view('view_name', 'view_display_name', $args);`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print $view->display['view_display_name']->display_options['title'];
```